# PHP mySQL, Joining More than Two Tables Together with Similar IDs?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is what I am working with:

```
$query = "SELECT Products.Title, Product_Lines.pl_Title, Manufacturers.man_Title".
 "FROM Products, Product_Lines, Manufacturers ".
    "WHERE Products.pl_ID = Product_Lines.pl_ID AND Product_Lines.man_ID = Manufacturers.man_ID";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['Title']. " - ". $row['pl_Title']. " - ". $row['man_Title'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Products.pl_ID = Product_Lines.pl_ID AND  
Product_Lines.man_ID = Manufactur' at line 1
```

I am unfamiliar with this method and this error

Comment: Are you trying to join these tables? If so, which are the foreign keys?

Comment: Could you give us your database structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Products.Title, Product_Lines.pl_Title, Manufacturers.man_Title
 FROM Products INNER JOIN Product_Lines ON Products.pl_ID = Product_Lines.pl_ID INNER JOIN Manufacturers ON Product_Lines.man_ID = Manufacturers.man_ID
```

WILL DO

Answer (score 2):

I don't see white space before your FROM clause. This is a possible cause for the error. Try:

```
$query = "SELECT Products.Title, Product_Lines.pl_Title, Manufacturers.man_Title".
 " FROM Products, Product_Lines, Manufacturers ".
    "WHERE Products.pl_ID = Product_Lines.pl_ID AND Product_Lines.man_ID = Manufacturers.man_ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

Need To follow two things

- Foriegn Key
- Join

Search `Join i.e [left join right join...]` In Inter u ll get anwser for ur question/..