# MySQL export specific fields from multiple table into one csv file? CREATE TABLE outputs

Tags: mysql, csv, export

I need to integrate my e-commerce with the local system.

I need to export specific fields from multiple tables of my database into a csv file.

I need from TABLE jos_virtuemart_products those fields product_sku , product_in_stock , low_stock_notification , product_length , product_width , product_height , product_weight

then

I need from TABLE jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb those fields purodct_name , product_s_desc

then the out put csv file should me imported to another database table that has all those fields from the others 2 table above.

Is it possible to be ran by mysql command in the linux command line? or I will have to figure out other way?

Have some one been in this situation?

Which is the best way to do this itegration?

Answer (score 1):

If you can write a query for what you want, you can use `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` to write it to a CSV file on the server.  Add `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` to set the separator to ',' as  the default is to use tabs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html

Comment: Hi Joshua, I did end up with this steps:                          1.TEE Results.csv

SELECT product_sku
FROM jos_virtuemart_products;

SELECT product_weight
FROM jos_virtuemart_products;

NOTEE

Comment: sorry got a little massed up with this comment, what i would like to say is that i create a file with this command TEE Results.csv

SELECT product_sku
FROM jos_virtuemart_products;

SELECT product_weight
FROM jos_virtuemart_products;

NOTEE
and then ran with this command: mysql -u root -p -h localhost table_name < tee.test and after it printed on my screen the columns it said that outfile is desable and couldn't create the file.

Comment: Okay according to [link]http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-commands.html[/link] I removed the ending line NOTEE so the out put now didn't show the outfile desable but either created a file???

Comment: Okay now I did it with SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE and it seems like this SELECT product_sku, product_in_stock, low_stock_notification, product_length, product_width, product_height, product_weight
INTO OUTFILE 'jos_virtuemart_products.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
FROM jos_virtuemart_products; but I need to get data from multiple tables and mixe them in the same out put file did you understand?

Comment: You need to join two tables together, something like: `SELECT * FROM jos_virtuemart_products AS a, jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb AS b WHERE a.product_sku=b.product_sku`.  You can also define your new table and move the data into the new table directly in MySQL: ``INSERT INTO newtable SELECT …``

Comment: Thanks Joshua gonna give a try!

Comment: Okay I can't I have created a github repo if you could help me? git@github.com:miranda-sjc/integracaodoestoque.git

Comment: Can you give me more INFo about the command SELECT * FROM jos_virtuemart_products AS a, jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb AS b WHERE a.product_sku=b.product_sku dind't get th WHERE part of this command

Comment: There's no information about the `jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb` table in the files you posted.   Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE  jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb` please?

Comment: It does not fit in here, do you have another way to contact you ?

Comment: Edit your question at the top to include the `CREATE TABLE ` outputs.

Comment: SELECT `virtuemart_product_id`, `product_sku`, `product_in_stock`, `low_stock_notification`, `product_width`, `product_length`, `product_height`, `product_weight` FROM `jos_virtuemart_products`;
SELECT `virtuemart_product_id`, `product_name`, `product_s_desc` FROM `jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb`;
SELECT `virtuemart_product_id`, `product_price` FROM `jos_virtuemart_product_prices`;
SELECT `virtuemart_manufacturer_id`, `mf_name` FROM `jos_virtuemart_manufacturers_en_gb`;
SELECT `virtuemart_category_id`, `category_name` FROM `jos_virtuemart_categories_en_gb`;

Comment: This code above out put everything i need but it is out putting without formatting take a look at the out put file here http://reydosom.com.br/exp.txt

Comment: Right now, you have several tables, one after another.  To get a single table, you'll need to `JOIN` the tables together on a field.  `virtuemart_product_id` is common to many, but not the last few.

Comment: So should I then have 2 files.csv other then 1 table?

Comment: till now I got this code : SELECT `virtuemart_product_id`, `product_price`, `product_name`, `product_s_desc`, `product_sku`, `product_in_stock`, `low_stock_notification`, `product_width`, `product_length`, `product_height`, `product_weight` FROM `jos_virtuemart_product_prices`, `jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb`,`jos_virtuemart_products` WHERE (jos_virtuemart_products.virtuemart_product_id=jos_virtuemart_product_prices.virtuemart_product_id, jos_virtuemart_products.virtuemart_product_id=jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb.virtuemart_product_id);

Comment: ... and getting this ERROR 1052 (23000) at line 1: Column 'virtuemart_product_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: You can use `jos_virtuemart_product_prices.virtuemart_product_id` to specify which table the column should come from.

Comment: Okay i got my goal done with this SELECT `product_price`, `product_name`, `product_s_desc`, `product_sku`, `product_in_stock`, `low_stock_notification`, `product_width`, `product_length`, `product_height`, `product_weight`
        FROM jos_virtuemart_products INNER JOIN  jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb ON jos_virtuemart_products.virtuemart_product_id = jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb.virtuemart_product_id INNER JOIN jos_virtuemart_product_prices ON jos_virtuemart_products_en_gb.virtuemart_product_id = jos_virtuemart_product_prices.virtuemart_product_id;

Answer (score 0):

If you can produce a query that results in the table for the new system (probably using some kind of join), you can export THAT to a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve my problem with help of @Joshua Martell and what has openned my eyes was this post [PHP mySQL, Joining More than Two Tables Together with Similar IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436897/php-mysql-joining-more-than-two-tables-together-with-similar-ids) with the answer from @Jatin Dhoot thank y'all!